# How to check which menu item has been selected in Form Load in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am running Joomla and using the ChronoForms plug component to create Forms.

I have a problem in that I want to set menu items on a menu in Joomla but want to make use of querystrings so more than one menu item might have the same Form Name but a different querystring. However it isn't possible to use querystrings in menu items with ChronoForms.

One possible solution I am investigating is to do away with querystrings and just check on Form Load which menu item has been selected and then process the form accordingly.

Has someone any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking here, but i you wish to have multiple menu items pointed to the same form, you can do this by manually editing the menu item alias. Am I following what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the menu link created by ChronoForms, when you add it to a menu (without querystring). You can use that as a base for an 'external URL', where you can add whatever you want to it.